# The cycle class map and the Hodge conjecture.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $ X $ be a compact complex algebraic manifold of dimension $ n $.

For each integer $ p \in \mathbb{N} $, let $ H^{p,p} (X) $ denotes the subspace of $ H^{2p} (X, \mathbb{C} ) $ of type $ (p,p) $.

The group of rational $ (p,p) $ - cycles : $ H^{p,p} (X , \mathbb{Q} ) = H^{2p} ( X , \mathbb{Q} ) \cap H^{p,p} (X) $ is called the group of rational Hodge classes of type $ (p,p) $.

An $ r $ -cycle of an algebraic variety $X$ is a formal finite linear combination $ \displaystyle \sum_{ i \in [1,h] } m_i Z_i $ of closed irreducible subvarieties $ Z_i $ of dimension $ r $ with integer coefficients $ m_i $.

The group of $ r $ - cycles is denoted by $ \mathcal{Z}_r (X) $.

On a compact complex algebraic manifold, the class of closed irreducible subvarieties of codimension $ p $ extends to a linear morphism :

$$ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } \ : \ \mathcal{Z}_p (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to H^{p,p} (X, \mathbb{Q} ) $$
defined by,
$$ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } \big( \displaystyle \sum_{ i \in [1,h] } m_i Z_i \big) = \displaystyle \sum_{ i \in [1,h] } m_i \eta_{Z_{i}} , \ \ \forall m_i \in \mathbb{Q} $$

The elements of the image of $ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } $ are called rational algebraic Hodge classes of type $ (p,p) $.

The Hodge conjecture says :

On a non-singular complex projective variety, any rational Hodge class of type $ (p,p) $ is algebraic, i.e : in the image of $ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } $.

- ***Question,***

In the last statement of the Hodge conjecture above, How to prove that, $ \exists Z \in \mathcal{Z}_p (X) \otimes \mathbb{Q} $, such that, $ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } (Z) \neq 0 $ ?.

In other words, How to show that, $ \mathrm{Im} \ \mathrm{cl}_{ \mathbb{Q} } \neq \{ 0 \} $ ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: This is far from my wheelhouse, but my first instinct would be to intersect an ample divisor with itself as many times as is necessary to reach the appropriate codimension. Does that do the job?

Comment: When you have a projective variety $X$, you have an embedding $i:X\to\mathbb{P}^N$ for some $N$. Then $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1)$ is a very ample line bundle whose Chern class $c_1$ is always a non trivial element of $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Q})$. In fact, for any $p\leq\dim X$, $c_1^p\in H^{p,p}(X,\mathbb{Q})$ is non trivial. This is essentially what Tabes Bridges suggested (with instead an ample divisor instead of a very ample one).

Comment: Ok. Thank you Roland and Tabes. It's clear now. :-)